# Concatenate Public IP output with Server Name

Tags: terraform

I have written a Terraform script to create a few Azure Virtual Machines.

The number of VMs created is based upon a variable called `type` in my `.tfvars` file:

`type = [ "Master-1", "Master-2", "Master-3", "Slave-1", "Slave-2", "Slave-3" ]`

My `variables.tf` file contains the following `local`:

`count_of_types = "${length(var.type)}"`

And my `resources.tf` file contains the code required to actual create the relevant number of VMs from this information:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  count                 = "${local.count_of_types}"
  name                  = "${replace(local.prefix_specific,"##TYPE##",var.type[count.index])}-VM"
  location              = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
  resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.main.*.id[count.index]}"]
  vm_size               = "Standard_B2ms"
  tags                  = "${local.tags}"
```

Finally, in my `output.tf` file, I output the IP address of each server:

```
output "public_ip_address" {
  value = ["${azurerm_public_ip.main.*.ip_address}"]
}
```

I am creating a Kubernetes cluster with 1x Master and 1x Slave VM. For this purpose, the script works fine - the first IP output is the Master and the second IP output is the Slave.

However, when I move to 8+ VMs in total, I'd like to know which IP refers to which VM.

Is there a way of amending my output to include the `type` local, or just the server's hostname *alongside* the Public IP?

E.g. `54.10.31.100 // Master-1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at formatlist (which is one of the functions for string manipulations) and can be used to iterate over the instance attributes and list tags and other attributes of interest.

```
output "ip-address-hostname" {
  value = "${
      formatlist(
        "%s:%s",
        azurerm_public_ip.resource_name.*.fqdn,
        azurerm_public_ip.resource_name.*.ip_address
      )
    }"
}
```

Note this is just a draft pseudo code. You may have to tweak this and create additional data sources in your TF file for effective enums

More reading available - https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/formatlist.html

Comment: As it stands this answer isn't particularly helpful other than pointing the OP in the right direction. It would be more complete if you could show how `formatlist` works, especially in the situation the OP has.

Comment: So theoretically I could use `formatlist` to concatenate two arrays... but how can I guarantee that the two arrays will "match up"? E.g. `Master-1` has the correct IP address.

Comment: That attributes for name and associated IP are expanded (discovered) at runtime. Just like a function call when you'd say something like print('%s'+' - '+'%s', HOST_NAME, HOST_IP)

Comment: You don't need the `+` there, you can use it as a printf-able string. And if you expanded your answer to show how to use it then that would save you from a half hearted explanation in the comments (which are subject to removal and not a first class citizen like answers are).

Answer (score 0):

[Raunak Jhawar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55099177) pointed me in the right direction, and therefore got the green tick.

For reference, here's the exact code I used in the end:

```
output "public_ip_address" {
  value = "${formatlist("%s: %s", azurerm_virtual_machine.vm.*.name, azurerm_public_ip.main.*.ip_address)}"
}
```

This resulted in the following output:

[image: Hostname/IP output]